# How can I conditionally apply a conduit?

Tags: haskell, conduit

I have a Conduit of type `Conduit a m a` and a function of type `(a -> Maybe a)`. I want to run the function, and then if it returns Nothing, use the Conduit. That is, I want a function of type

```
maybePipe :: Conduit a m b -> (a -> Maybe b) -> Conduit a m b
```

or, of the more restricted type

```
maybePipe :: Conduit a m a -> (a -> Maybe a) -> Conduit a m a
```

If it helps, my specific case is as follows:

I'm writing code that deals with IRC messages, and I have a function:

```
runClient :: Conduit IRC.Message IO IRC.Message -> ClientSettings -> IO ()
runClient pipe address = runTCPClient' pipe' address where
    pipe' = mapC IRC.decode $= concatMapC id $= pipe $= mapC IRC.encode $= mapC (++ "\r\n")
    handlePings (IRC.Message (Just (IRC.Server serverName)) "PING" []) = Just $ IRC.pong serverName
    handlePings (IRC.Message Nothing "PING" [server]) = Just $ IRC.pong server
    handlePings (IRC.Message Nothing "PING" []) = Just $ IRC.pong (getHost address)
    handlePings _ = Nothing
    runTCPClient' :: Conduit ByteString IO ByteString -> ClientSettings -> IO ()
    runTCPClient' pipe address = runTCPClient address runClient where
        runClient appdata = appSource appdata $= linesUnboundedAsciiC $= pipe $$ appSink appdata
```

I want to be able to do `maybePipe handlePings pipe` (or equivalent) in that function, so when the IRC message is a ping, we respond with a pong and don't call the user-specified Conduit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Michael's combinator only calls the `(a -> Maybe b)` on the first item it comes acress, then lets the `onNothing` pipe take over. This was not what I was looking for.

Instead, using `ZipConduit`, in my specific example (using `conduit-combinators`):

```
pingHandlingPipe = 
  getZipConduit $ ZipConduit (concatMapC handlePings) 
               *> ZipConduit (takeWhileC (not.isJust.handlePings) $= pipe)
```

or, generalized

```
pipeMaybe maybeF pipe = 
  getZipConduit $ ZipConduit (concatMapC maybeF)
               *> ZipConduit (takeWhileC (not.isJust.maybeF) $= pipe)
```

Unfortunately, this calls the `(a -> Maybe b)` function two times.

Comment: You could first `mapC maybeF` then fuse that with your zipped conduits.

Answer (score 2):

[Searching Hoogle](https://www.fpcomplete.com/hoogle?q=Conduit+a+m+b+-%3E+%28a+-%3E+Maybe+b%29+-%3E+Conduit+a+m+b&env=ghc-7.4.2-stable-13.09) reveals a function with almost exactly that type signature: [mapOutputMaybe](http://haddocks.fpcomplete.com/fp/7.4.2/20130829-168/conduit/Data-Conduit.html#v%3amapOutputMaybe). But the more idiomatic way would be to fuse with `Data.Conduit.List.mapMaybe`.

**EDIT**

Scratch that, I understand what you're asking now. No, there's no built in combinator. But it's easy to build one up:

```
myHelper onNothing f = awaitForever $ maybe onNothing yield . f
```

Comment: I was under the impression that both of these removed Nothings, am I mistaken?